# Where is my logic failing?

Tags: c++, loops

I am done the work-- but my output is odd. I am basically trying to compare a bunch of objects and if they share ttns and their time is up-- then they need to recalculate their ttns. After checking all the hosts I increment the clock and try again. The objective is to find the fist host which can make it through the check without a collision. This is basically a simulation of a network that does some backoff calculation if two hosts send at the same time (CLOCK). I put in a check to ensure the host didn't check  itself-- I know what my expected output is and it isn't it. I have worked through this a few times but can't find my logic error(s). Any pointers?

```
// Should insert n number as argument 1 on the command line. 
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h> // srand(), time()

static int CLOCK = 0;

class Host{
  private:
    int sid;
    int cc;
    int ttns;

  public:
    Host();
    int get_sid(){ return sid; }
    void set_sid(int id){ sid = id; }
    int get_cc(){ return cc; }
    void inc_cc(){ cc += 1; }
    int get_ttns(){ return ttns; }
    void new_ttns(){ ttns = (rand()%(cc+1))+CLOCK+1; }
  };

Host::Host(){
  sid  = -666;
  cc   = 0;
  ttns = 0;
}

bool work(std::vector<Host> &hosts){
  int count = 0;

  for(CLOCK = 0; /*INFINITE*/; CLOCK++){
      for(int i = 0; i < hosts.size(); i++){
        count = 0;
          for(int n = 0; n < hosts.size(); n++){
              if( (i != n) && /* host i doesn't compare to host n */
                  (hosts[i].get_ttns() == hosts[n].get_ttns()) &&/* host i and n share ttns */ 
                  (hosts[i].get_ttns() == CLOCK)  /* host i ttns = now */
                ){ 
                hosts[i].inc_cc();
                hosts[i].new_ttns(); 
                count = -666; // collision occured
              }
          count++;
          }
        if ( count == hosts.size() ){
          std::cout << "Host " << hosts[i].get_sid() << "\nTTNS: " << hosts[i].get_ttns();
          std::cout << std::endl;
          return false;
        }
     } 
  }

  return true; // pretty pointless
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  srand(time(NULL));
  std::vector<Host> hosts;

  // Push hosts into vector
  int nhosts = atoi(argv[1]);
  for(int i = 0; i < nhosts; i++){
    Host newhost;
    newhost.set_sid(i);
    hosts.push_back(newhost);
  }

  while (work(hosts)){
    ; // hang out 
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What output is produced, what do you expect?

Comment: I was told by professors the output (TTNS of the first successful host) should be around 11 for 20 hosts, around 20 for 40 hosts and around 45 for 100 hosts. It should continue to increase linearly as you increase n number of hosts.

Comment: what is the output of your implementation?

Comment: @duedl0r I am getting a random host usually the last host at time 0.

Answer (score 1):

one of the error is probably in this line:

```
(hosts[i].get_ttns() == CLOCK)
```

you can't compare this, since CLOCK is global and incremented by more than one host. that means a host doesn't have a monotonous CLOCK.

maybe you want this:

```
(hosts[i].get_ttns() <= CLOCK
```

Comment: Hmm, if clock is global shouldn't it be incremented? If that doesn't work, then the for loop wouldn't increment clock either? The for loop was suppose to increment clock at least in my designs. Maybe make CLOCK local to the work function?

Comment: ah no..I was wrong :) the hosts don't get executed concurrently.. my bad :/ but making it local is better..I got confused hehe

Comment: Oh-- well thanks for taking a look. I have been stumped for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you should update the cc and ttns for the host n you are checking for in the inner loop.

```
            hosts[n].inc_cc();
            hosts[n].new_ttns();
```

Instead of

```
            hosts[i].inc_cc();
            hosts[i].new_ttns();
```

And move the check for

```
    ( hosts[i].get_ttns() == CLOCK )
```

outside the inner loop.

```
    if ( hosts[i].get_ttns() == CLOCK )
      for(int n = 0; n < hosts.size(); n++){
```

The condition inside then becomes

```
           if( (i != n) && /* host i doesn't compare to host n */
              (hosts[i].get_ttns() == hosts[n].get_ttns()) /* host i and n share ttns */
           ){
```

This way you don't `count++` for invalid hosts.

Comment: Actually, I think when you get a collision BOTH sending parties back off, and attempt retransmit later. So both hosts[n] and hosts[i] should be modified.

Comment: In that case the loops need to break and the structure rewritten quite a bit. This way a collision is marked only once, instead of N times for the first loop.